# How to use flatmap with Result in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

So, I have this function which is copied from [this](https://gist.github.com/kean/64b9fc0963fd430594fdb3eb848bccf3) GitHub gist.

```
protocol ClientProtocol {
    func request<Response: Codable>(_ endpoint: Endpoint<Response>)-> Single<Response>
}

final class Client: ClientProtocol {
    
    private let manager: Alamofire.Session
    private let baseURL = URL(string: "http://192.168.20:8080")!
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "<your_queue_label>")
    
    init(accessToken: String) {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.headers.add(name: "Authorization", value: "Bearer \(accessToken)")
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
        self.manager = Alamofire.Session.init(configuration: configuration)
        //self.manager.retrier = OAuth2Retrier()
    }
    
    func request<Response>(_ endpoint: Endpoint<Response>) -> Single<Response> {
        return Single<Response>.create { observer in
            let request = self.manager.request(
                self.url(path: endpoint.path),
                method: httpMethod(from: endpoint.method),
                parameters: endpoint.parameters
            )
            request
                .validate()
                .responseData(queue: self.queue) { response in
                    let result: Result<Response, AFError> = response.result.flatMap(endpoint.decode)
                    switch result {
                        case let .success(val): observer(.success(val))
                        case let .failure(err): observer(.error(err))
                    }
                }
            return Disposables.create {
                request.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func url(path: Path) -> URL {
        return baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
    }
}

private func httpMethod(from method: Method) -> Alamofire.HTTPMethod {
    switch method {
        case .get: return .get
        case .post: return .post
        case .put: return .put
        case .patch: return .patch
        case .delete: return .delete
    }
}


private class OAuth2Retrier: Alamofire.RequestRetrier {
    func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
        if (error as? AFError)?.responseCode == 401 {
            // TODO: implement your Auth2 refresh flow
            // See https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#adapting-and-retrying-requests
        }
        // completion(false, 0)
    }
}
```

**Endpoint**

```
// MARK: Defines
typealias Parameters = [String: Any]
typealias Path = String

enum Method {
    case get, post, put, patch, delete
}


// MARK: Endpoint
final class Endpoint<Response> {
    
    let method: Method
    let path: Path
    let parameters: Parameters?
    let decode: (Data) throws -> Response
    
    init(method: Method = .get, path: Path, parameters: Parameters? = nil, decode: @escaping (Data) throws -> Response) {
        self.method = method
        self.path = path
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.decode = decode
    }
}


// MARK: Convenience
extension Endpoint where Response: Swift.Decodable {
    convenience init(method: Method = .get,  path: Path,  parameters: Parameters? = nil) {
        self.init(method: method, path: path, parameters: parameters) {
            try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: $0)
        }
    }
}


extension Endpoint where Response == Void {
    convenience init(method: Method = .get, path: Path, parameters: Parameters? = nil) {
        self.init(method: method, path: path, parameters: parameters, decode: { _ in () })
    }
}
```

At `let result = response.result.flatMap(endpoint.decode)` xCode is throwing

> `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

The type of the `response.result` is `Result<Data, AFError>`

I want to flatmap it to `Result< Response, AFError>`.

I tried

```
let result = response.result.flatMap { (data) -> Result<Response, AFError> in
 // don't know what to put here
}
```

Comment: I just tried the gist with `Alamofire` v4.9.1 and got not compilation error in `request(_:)`

Comment: I'm using 5.2.0

Comment: Then I get [No type named 'SessionManager' in module 'Alamofire'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64496852/1425697). It might be useful to provide this kind of information in your question

Comment: Sorry, but I already fixed all the issues. It is just a flat map think I thought it is not important.

Comment: You fixed all the issues, but you still provided the link to the gist. How can you be sure that people will solve the issues the same way you did ? IMHO you did not provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @AnderCover please now take a look updated.

Comment: now `let result: Result<Response, AFError> = response.result.flatMap(endpoint.decode)` causes `Cannot convert value of type '(Data) throws -> Response' to expected argument type '(Data) -> Result<Response, AFError>'`

Comment: and `case let .failure(err): observer(.error(err))` causes `Type 'Result<PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, Response>.Element, Error>' (aka 'Result<Response, Error>') has no member 'error'`

Comment: what version of RxSwift are you using ?

Comment: Rx version: 6.2.0

Comment: @AnderCover sorry I'm using the 5.4.3 version of Alamofire.

Comment: see my answer, and tell me if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`flatMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/3139395-flatmap) doesn't take throwing closure and in `EndPoint`, decode is a throwing closure :

```
let decode: (Data) throws -> Response
```

try catching the error:

```
func request<Response>(_ endpoint: Endpoint<Response>) -> Single<Response> {
    return Single<Response>.create { observer in
        let request = self.manager.request(
            self.url(path: endpoint.path),
            method: httpMethod(from: endpoint.method),
            parameters: endpoint.parameters
        )
        request
            .validate()
            .responseData(queue: self.queue) { response in
                let result: Result<Response, AFError> = response.result.flatMap {
                    do {
                        return Result<Response, AFError>.success(try endpoint.decode($0))
                    } catch let error as AFError {
                        return Result<Response, AFError>.failure(error)
                    } catch {
                        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                switch result {
                    case let .success(val): observer(.success(val))
                    case let .failure(err): observer(.failure(err))
                }
            }
        return Disposables.create {
            request.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Note

Since you seem only interested in `AFError` this code will call `fatalError` this may not a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `flatMap` when you should be using `map`...

```
func example(response: Response, endpoint: Endpoint<Thing>) {
    let result = response.result.map(endpoint.decode)
}

struct Response {
    let result: Result<Data, Error>
}

struct Endpoint<T> {
    func decode(_ data: Data) -> T { fatalError() }
}

struct Thing { }
```